# Installation of Workflow Manager for SharePoint 2016 Server

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, workflow-manager

I have Installed SharePoint 2016 to server with SQL Server 2014(latest service pack).

i able to create 2010 based workflow using SharePoint Designer 2013 into SharePoint 2016 but option not available in drop down to create 2013 based workflow, so i have installed workflow manager to SharePoint 2016 server as per the provided from below links.

[SharePoint 2016: Step By Step Installation of Workflow Manager](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34407.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx)

Installation has been successfully completed and able to configure workflow farm however i am not able to [Register Workflow Service Proxy](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34462.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-guid-to-register-workflow-service-proxy.aspx).
it gives an error as shows in below image

**Register-SPWorkflowService : Workflow XAML failed validation due to the following errors:
Cannot create unknown type**

[image]

I have spent much time to resolve this issue but no luck.

I do really appreciate if someone can help me to resolve the issue, Thanks

Comment: did you install WFM on separate server than SharePoint? Did you install the Workflow Manager Client on all sharepoint servers?

Comment: What version of WFM u installed? did you apply the hotfix as well?

Comment: For testing purposes try registering workflow service on another site collection. Similar issues occur when where some errors in Workflow Manager database data.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMVP, WFM installed on same SharePoint Server and all things, please look bottom in this link i perfomed all 8 steps which provided
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/34407.sharepoint-2016-step-by-step-installation-of-workflow-manager.aspx

Comment: @ECM4D, already tried with creating new web application, same issue

Answer (score 3):

The Workflow Manager farm can be a hassle to get right, but I assume when you browse to `http://localhost:12291/` with IE running as Administrator, you see the underlying XML notation?

[image]

Also, when you look at the Workflow Service Application Proxy in Service Applications on URL `http://CentralAdminURL/_admin/WorkflowServiceStatus.aspx`, you see **Workflow is Connected**

[image]

Installing and configuring the Workflow Manager farm several times, I've come to the conclusion that Spence Harbar explains things the right way in his series [Workflow Manager Farms for SharePoint 2013 Part One: Core Concepts, High Availability, Certificate and SharePoint considerations part 1](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm1.aspx) and [part 2](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm2.aspx) and [part 3](http://www.harbar.net/articles/wfm3.aspx).

Comment: Yes i got screen which you provided for xml location but got errors in workflow service status page saying workflow is not connected, because of registring not successful of workflow service proxy.
let me check Harbar links which you provided and let you know, thanks benny

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to make sure that the `http://{centralAdmin}/_admin/WebApplicationList.aspx` and the "Service Connections" for the SharePoint Central Administration Application were enabled to allow the `http://{centralAdmin}/_admin/WorkflowServiceStatus.aspx` to work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

See ULS logs filtered by powershell.exe
In my case this error was caused by missing `Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.Activities.dll`

in `~16/template/workflowActivities`

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, you need to download and install service bus 1.0 cummilative update 1 and update 3. I have written a detailed article on how you can configure workflow manager for sharepoint 2016 and also how you can resolve the issue:
Register-SPWorkflowService : Workflow XAML failed validation due to the
following errors:
Invalid type(s) 'Microsoft.Activities.CacheScope'. Check in the below url:
http://www.enjoysharepoint.com/Articles/Details/configure-workflow-manager-sharepoint-2016-workflow-in-windows-server-2012-r2-21546.aspx